# Grey border appearing around svg images on retina devices

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

http://prosepticwp.cloud-2.co.uk/surveys-inspections/ - The blue icons on this page are getting a grey border when viewed on retina devices (iPhone X this problem shows)

I have checked for border css properties but none are set. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: can you any of your code?

Comment: I saw the website with retina but I've not saw any border around the icons

Comment: Check it out on iPhone x (I have added images now aswell)

Comment: <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/Home Buyar Drainage Surveys.svg" alt="Home Buyer Drainage Surveys" /> -- That is the code.

Comment: Please remove down points I was 1 rep point away from commenting everywhere :( :(

Comment: You should write an actual answer rather than editing your question to contain an answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ahh did not know I can do that, that is done now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vertical-align: middle; - This was causing the weird thin grey border to appear around my svg images on chrome. Hopefully, this helps someone else!